# Any boxing issues with a big list of booleans? Any alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, list, boxing

I need a list of booleans (size anywhere from 200 to 200k). If i use `System.Collections.Generic.List<bool>` I'm going to suffer from serious boxing issues (correct me if I'm wrong).

What are the alternatives? (of course i know i can use a boolean array but i need to be able to add and remove things easily from the array)

Edit:

another question i have is (similarly to the top question,) what if i need a list of integers, what solutions do i have?

Comment: Define big... 200 items, 2000 items, 2,000,000 items?

Comment: Please don't put "c# vb.net: " in your titles. Just leave those in the tags. And in any case, "VB.NET" is one word.

Comment: List<int> for your list of integers.

Comment: The whole point of generics is that they alleviate any boxing concerns. You can specify *any* type that you want for the `<T>` section. So you can have a `List<bool>` or a `List<int>` or a `List<MyCustomClass>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this:

http://www.dijksterhuis.org/exploring-boxing/

The generic list completely removes the boxing issues.

Also, I've held that many ints, strings, etc in a List many times with no performance issues.  In fact, I've held up to 1,000,000 before without a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `BitArray` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx

Edit: If space is your concern, the `BitArray` is 8 times smaller than a `List<bool>`. A `BitArray` will use one bit per boolean, whereas a `List<bool>` will use 8 bits per boolean.

Comment: Do you need to add and remove from the end of the list? If so, you can just set the Length property appropriately. If you need to insert and remove in the middle of the list, it is possible with the BitArray, by manually shifting all values after the insert/remove location. But this is probably not ideal for performance. Edit: Actually, I'm not so sure this is bad for performance. If you look at the `List<T>` implementation for insert, it shifts all values after the insert point with an Array.Copy call, which is a linear time operation, same as shifting bits in the BitArray.

Comment: @MikeDour: An insertion operation within the middle of any array-ish type is apt to be O(N), but the constant associated with copying individual items in a `BitArray` is apt to be much worse than for `Array.Copy`, even though a `BitArray` which contained its own insertion logic could probably manage a per-item time that would be less than for a `List<bool>` since it could take care of 32 items at once.